# How To Merge Two Images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I want to merge two images, it doesn't mean that I'm trying to learn any Photo-editing software(like Adobe).

So I just want to merge two image, so I need some online tool to do this(because I don't want to install any photo-editing software for doing **this** stuff), I searched Google but I didn't found any tool, that is **Free** to use, so anyone could help me with this.

Comment: technically this is a webapps question, but I think you really should learn how to use a basic image editing program on your PC, first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does what you want: http://www.makeuseof.com/dir/imagemerger-merge-images-online/

For some more control over what is happening, I'd suggest you install GIMP as a free PS replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your platform you could try out [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=moreinfo_viewers).
It has a 30 day free trial period...